# Firefox 100% overflow DIV in a 100% table cell exeeds content size

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser

I have the following code which displays correct in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox.
In Firefox, the scroller of the second row exceeds the display size (vertical).
Is there a workaround available for this problem?

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SYTxd/).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body,html {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                overflow:hidden;
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            table {
                table-layout: fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table height="100%" border="1">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td style="height:100px">
                    first row
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:100%">
                    <div style="height:100%;overflow-y:scroll">
                        scroll content begin<br>
                        1<br><br><br><br>
                        2<br><br><br><br>
                        3<br><br><br><br>
                        4<br><br><br><br>
                        5<br><br><br><br>
                        6<br><br><br><br>
                        7<br><br><br><br>
                        8<br><br><br><br>
                        9<br><br><br><br>
                        10<br><br><br><br>
                        11<br><br><br><br>
                        12<br><br><br><br>
                        13<br><br><br><br>
                        14<br><br><br><br>
                        15<br><br><br><br>
                        16<br><br><br><br>
                        17<br><br><br><br>
                        18<br><br><br><br>

                        scroll content end
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid/incomplete, it is at least missing the closing `</td>` and `</tr>`.

Comment: that true but it does not solve my problem!

Comment: @helmi you can specify the height in percentage itself as similar to frst td?

Comment: On jsFiddle, with right tags and quotes, I haven't problems.. Chrome and Firefox work in the same way...

I'm using Linux Mint with Chrome 26.0.1410.63 and Firefox 20.0

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Feq2W/2/

Comment: Strange issue. I worked till now with no result :(. Change your html markup or wait for a solution.

Comment: @Alesanco i use ff 20.0.1 and it shows the scrollbar but the content is not scrollable in chrome it works fine please check it again

Comment: @Mr_Green yes i too i worked many hours to find a solution but no chance. change the markup is not so easy!

Comment: if the layout is fixed, then give `position: absolute` to the `div` element. Something like this.. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/SYTxd/4/)(_Updated_).